# column spacing and regular spacing between brackets... also IPA characters input

Tags: tables, tipa

Here is a sample of a table with multi-language scripts. The actual table has 5 x 3 columns. First I'd like regular spacing between the brackets. The content there never crosses 3 characters, therefore the space could be set equal to 3 characters. Not a length in mm, cm... It must work at different fontsize too.

For the column spacing `@{\hspace{6mm}}`, I'd like to replace the length similarly to above with a font size depending value (2 or 3 characters).

Feel free to add your own tricks to make it look nice.

How can I get rid of the following warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T3/lmss/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T3/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 357.

))) (./sample.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T3/latinmodernsans(0)/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T3/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 28.

[1{/usr/share/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./sample.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

)
```

my mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}
\usepackage{fontsize,fix-cm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{latin modern sans}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifontsf{NotoSansDevanagari}[Script=Devanagari]
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont{NotoSansDevanagari}[Script=Devanagari]
\setlanguagealias{sanskrit}{sam}

\usepackage{tipa} %
\newcommand{\ipa}[1]{\textipa{\bfseries #1}}

\changefontsize{12}
\makeatletter
\let\@normalsize\normalsize
\makeatother
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll@{\hspace{6mm}}lll}
\textsam{त} & ta & \ipa{[t2]} & \textsam{थ} & tha & \ipa{[t\super{h}2]} \\
%
\textsam{प} & pa & \ipa{[p2]} & \textsam{फ} & pha & \ipa{[p\super{h}2]} \\
%
\textsam{य} & ya & \ipa{[j2]} & \textsam{र} & ra & \ipa{[r2]}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

EDIT:

here is a solution that works nicely:

```
\begin{tabular}{l l @{[} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3.7ex} @{]}@{\qquad}%
                l l @{[} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3.7ex} @{]}}
```

here is the result:
[image]

Comment: as you are using a Unicode TeX you could use Unicode IPA rather than legacy 8bit IPA T3-encoded fonts

Comment: i did not know that tipa was a legacy package. I just tried "Doulos SIL" font, i need to figure out how to input something like "t\super{h}ʌ" in one shot.

Comment: See `unitipa`/`tipauni` packages - the tipa shortcuts are usable and produce Unicode output.

Comment: yes tipauni. Anyway, using only fontspec and a proper font, and inputing the character through their hex codes with ^U combo was almost fine. I still need to make a macro which optionally will handle superscript.

Comment: @user1850133 The superscripts have their own Unicodes, you don't need a macro. For example U+2B0 gives ʰ.

Comment: @wipet probably for latin alphabet. Does 'ɦ' have a superscript version and is that supported by many fonts? A macro to transform a regular character into superscript or subscript is a better thing

Answer (score 0):

For the spacing, you could use the \phantom function, which creates an empty box with the size corresponding to its argument.

Thus, instead of having a \hskip in your tabular environment, just add a new column and have \phantom{abc} in it.

It's probably not the nicest solution, but it does the trick and you can format the text in it to make sure it matches whichever font and size you decide to use.

There's the even more obvious solution, making a cell and writing the text in white, but that can be problematic at times.

Comment: You could as well use `@{\phantom{abc}` in the `tabular` preamble. Or you could use `\hskip1.5em` (since `em` and `ex` are font dependent lengths)

Comment: could you show a complete example?